# Line Breaks Inside Jade Templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I was looking around for a solution to include a line break inside a title.  The normal fixes for this are to include an actual line break inside your code...

```
<div title="Ron
Swanson"></div>
```

Or to use `&#013;` in place of your new line, like so...

```
<div title="Ron &#013;Swanson"></div>
```

These solutions work fine, however since I'm using Jade as a templating engine, I can't properly include a line break inside my code...

```
.title(title="Ron
Swanson")
```

--OR--

```
.title(title="Ron\
Swanson")
```

Without the `\` it throws a syntax error, and with it doesn't actually insert a line break.  Also `.title(title="Ron Swanson") prints out those characters literally.

What is the correct way of including line breaks in your Jade templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use `\n` to represent a new line (just like a JavaScript string).  Doing something like this will work...

```
.title(title="Ron\nSwanson")
```